# Can washington residents play online poker fundraiser?

Tags: washington, gambling

Can a Washington State resident play poker online for a fund-raiser that's hosted by an organization outside of the state of Washington?

Comment: https://www.wsgc.wa.gov/about-us/frequently-asked-questions/online-gambling-faq

Comment: This page doesn't talk about fund-raising events though. I know fund-raisers are some times treated differently.